# IAR 6.50.6 STM32F217 USB + Ethernet works intermittently

Tags: c, usb, ethernet, stm32, iar

Using IAR EWARM 6.50.6 for ARM M3, on a custom board with a STM32F217VET6 micro.  Board has Full Speed USB 2.0 that I am using in device mode as a custom HID, 10/100 Ethernet, misc GPIO, SPI and I2C in use.  No OS, just C code.  Release build, no watchdog enabled (was before all this debugging), no optimizations.  Latest libraries from ST.  Ethernet uses its own 50 MHz crystal, RMII mode.  Micro is 120 MHz and uses a 25 MHz crystal.

If I have both USB and Ethernet enabled, along with all the other stuff, the USB fails to come up on some boards, but it does work on other boards.  Ethernet and other peripherals work, the only problem is the USB.  Windows device manager says code 10, cannot start device.

If I include the Ethernet code but do not call it (protect it via a large counter to delay it from being touched until a long time period has elapsed, which keeps it linked in), the USB still does not work on those affected boards.  Even though the Ethernet code is included in the image and never called, the USB still fails to work.

If I comment out the calls to the Ethernet so that code never gets linked in, the USB works on those affected boards.

So the USB and Ethernet both work if called separately on those boards, just not together.  But on other boards, they do work together, same compiled code.  Confused?!?

I have been trying all kinds of changes to the code to change the order in which the different peripherals are initialized, and accessed.  I have tried adding different delays throughout the code.  Tried disabling various peripherals, changing the frequency the USB and Ethernet are serviced, IRQ priorities, heap, stack, customer linker settings, etc.  No matter what I have tried, nothing makes a difference, USB still fails.

Has anybody ever seen something like this before?  If so, what was the root cause?  If not, any ideas what is going on?  I have run out of things to try, getting ready to scrap a bunch of boards.  Suggestions?

Thanks in advance for your help.
Dave

Comment: I assume they are too large for key-ring-bling, to light to be paper-weights,... __I know, I'm no help__.  However, without access to the hardware and source code, I can't do much more than throw popcorn.  Sorry.

Comment: I have only worked with Cortex-M3s from NXP, and I am not 100% sure, but seem to remember that in there was part of the RAM was AHB-RAM (what ever that means...) which *had* to be used for variables which were accessed for USB/Ethernet interrupt routines. Maybe STM has something similar, and you need to adjust linker settings to force placement of those variables to specific RAM sections.

Comment: Did you also comment out all the initialization code (clocks, pins, etc) for the 2 modules in your tests?

Comment: Yes, all parts of the code related to a peripheral are #ifdef protected, so I can easily add/remove any peripheral not needed.  What I found really strange is that simply having the Ethernet code linked in but not called (crazy long delay after power up before code is actually called) affected the USB.  After I removed the Ethernet calls via a #define and the linker excluded all that code, did the USB work.  Very odd.